# injector:modulerr error when i try to load angular js inside Full Calender

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to load a simple full calender plugin and on click of each date i am trying to show a sample modal dialog that shows the user the option of selelcting the organization and branch which are fetched from the database , but the angular module is not getting loaded and the variables are not evaluated it stays as {{org.orgname}} and {{branch.branchName}}

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
            {
            var ScheduleApp = angular.module('ScheduleApp', ['ui.calendar','ui.bootstrap']);
            ScheduleApp.controller('ScheduleAppContoller', function($scope,$http) {

                $scope.organizations = [];
                $scope.organization = "";

                $scope.branches = [];
                $scope.branch = "";
                //$scope.managedEntities = [];

                var getOrganization = "getOrganizations";
                $http.post(getOrganization).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.organizations = data;
                });

                $scope.selectBranch = function() {
var orgId = $scope.organization;
                    var action = "getBranchByOrgId?";
                    var param = "orgId=" + orgId;

                    $http.post(action + param).success(function(data) {
                        $scope.branches = data;
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

and my html

```
<body  ng-app="ScheduleApp">
    <div id='calendar' style="Width: 90%; padding-left: 10%"></div>
    <div  id="createEventModal" class="well modal fade" tabindex="-1" style="Width: 40%; height: 550px; margin-left: 30%; margin-top: 20px;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true"  ng-controller="ScheduleAppContoller">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel1">Create a new Schedule</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="createAppointmentForm" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch " class="col-sm-5 control-label2">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="scheduleTitle" id="scheduleTitle"
                            class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead"> <input
                            type="hidden" id="apptStartTime" /> <input type="hidden"
                            id="apptEndTime" /> <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch " class="col-sm-5 control-label2">Managed
                        Entity Group:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <input type="text" name="patientName" id="patientName"
                            class="form-control" style="margin: 0 auto;"
                            data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4"> <input
                            type="hidden" id="apptStartTime" /> <input type="hidden"
                            id="apptEndTime" /> <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch " class="col-sm-5 control-label2">Organization
                        :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="organization"
                            ng-change="selectBranch()" id="organizationId"
                            name="organizationId">
                            <option value="">Please select Organization</option>
                            <option
                                ng-repeat="organization in organizations|orderBy:'orgName'"
                                value="{{organization.orgId}}">{{organization.orgName}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch " class="col-sm-5 control-label2">Branch:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="branch" name="branchId"
                            id="branchId" name="branchId" style="width: auto;">
                            <option value="">Please Select Branch</option>
                            <option value="{{br.id}}"
                                ng-repeat="br in branches | orderBy:branchName">{{br.branchName}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch " class="col-sm-5 control-label2">Checklist
                        Type:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="patientName" id="patientName"
                            style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4"
                            class="form-control"> <input type="hidden"
                            id="apptStartTime" /> <input type="hidden" id="apptEndTime" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch " class="col-sm-5 control-label2">Add
                        Recurrence Rule</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="isRecurrencePresent"
                            id="isRecurrencePresent" style="margin: 0 auto;"
                            data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The calender is loaded properly and so is the modal dialog but im not able to load the drop down within this modal

Comment: could you make a plunker please ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WcmsGA0DDcNWZxU1AwD2?p=preview is the plunker but the full calender is not opening in it , its taking lot of time . a little new to  plunkr in adding plugins

Answer (score 0):

ok I've change your import, because some of them were wrong (wrong order), so now we got a fullcalendar working with no errors on a console in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gx2tLTPCExV2elqgVw6n) if I understand this correct you want to call `$scope.selectBranch = function() {...}` and get all you brunches from $http ? when  `ng-change="selectBranch()"` is trigger?! but selectBrunch is never trigger as there is nothing changing in that dropdown. You will need to load your 'Organization' before to use ng-change.

If you want to use $http to populate your  you can check [Typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), hope it helps, please let me know if you need some help.

Comment: yes @macrog , but the organization is not getting loaded it is giving a injector:modulerr i have commented the ng-app  in body tag and also removed the ng-contoller in  createEventModal div